# Submodules of $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ with $R$ a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

> Is there a way to characterize the submodules of the $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$?

$M,N$ are arbitrary $R$-modules and $R$ a commutative ring, to assure that $\operatorname{Hom}$ will be an $R$-module.

Someone optimistic would say that these submodules are in a bijective correspondence with the submodules of $N$, but I seriously doubt it.

**Edit.** My question goes to if there is a relation between the submodules of $N$ and the submodules of $\operatorname{Hom}$, supposing you know the submodules of $N$ and $M$.

Comment: Why would someone say that? What would the correspondence be? (And it's obviously wrong; take $R = N = k$ a field and $\dim M > 1$.) Anyway, I'm not sure what you're looking for as an answer. If $M = R$ then this is just the problem of characterizing the submodules of an arbitrary $R$-module $N$, which seems hard in general.

Comment: My question goes to if there is a relation between the submodules of N and the submodules of the Hom, supposing you knew the submodules of N and M.

Comment: @DavidBecharaSenior Consider editing your last comment into your question: it helps clarify quite a bit about what you're asking.

Comment: this last question in your comment is more reasonable but, in general, the submodules of $M$ and $N$ are not enough to classify all the subgroups of $Hom(M,N)$. For an easy example take a field $k$, $N=k$ and $M=\bigoplus_{\mathbb N}k$ (a vector space of countable infinite dimension). Then $Hom(M,N)\cong \prod_{\mathbb N}k$ has uncountably many submodules... so this information cannot be encoded in terms of the countable sets of submodules of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Simone,  I needed an example to be sure about that.

Comment: @YACP Yes, it is a good idea... I'll do it soon with some more comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was commenting, the question in your comment and in your edit is more precise and can be answered, while the original question is quite more general and I cannot say if something can be said.

In general, the submodules of $M$ and $N$ are not enough to classify all the submodules of $Hom(M,N)$.

For an easy example take a field $k$, $N=k$ and $M=\bigoplus_\mathbb N k$ (a vector space of countable infinite dimension). Then, $Hom(M,N)≅\prod_\mathbb N k$ has uncountably many submodules, so this information cannot be encoded in terms of the countable sets of submodules of $M$ and $N$.

Let us remain for a while in a similar setting to the above example, that is, $k$ is a field, $M$ is any vector space and $N=k$. Then, it is possible to endow the $k$-vector space $M^*=Hom(M,k)$ with a linear topology which is called the pointwise convergence topology, which makes $M^*$ into a linearly compact topological vector space. It is a classical result that there is a bijective correspondence between the sub-vector spaces of $M$ and the **closed** sub-vector spaces of $M^*$ (this is a consequence of the so-called Lefschetz duality, which is a particular case of the MacDonald duality which works over complete local noetherian commutative rings). This can be seen as a result that goes in the direction you are interested in...